# DotNetNuke installation

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to download setup DotNetNuke on my development PC, which contains IIS7 and SQL Server 2008.  I have followed the instructions here: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/19/View/Details/How-To-Install-DotNetNuke-On-Your-Computer.aspx.

When I navigate to localhost nothing happens.  When I navigate to this page in Firefox it says: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

I have looked at lots of post entries and tried different things.  This looked promising but did not help: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/107/threadid/180233/scope/posts.aspx.

Most of the suggestions seem to be for developers that are upgrading websites.  Is there a log file anywhere that can tell me exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The logs can be found in /Portals/_default/Logs .

You can increase the log sensitivity by editing DotNetNuke.log4net.config.  Use

```
    <level value="All" />
```

for the most detailed log messages.

```
    <level value="Error" />
```

may also work if All provides too much info.